# Is there a way to turn off script parsing in PowerShell and execute commands with raw arguments?

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to pass raw arguments to commands through PowerShell but it's failing. PowerShell tries to evaluate the arguments before they get passed to commands and as a result the commands get the wrong arguments. Does anyone know if there is a mode in PowerShell that would treat commands and arguments as they're typed? Alternatively, does anyone know the PowerScript quoting rules so I can escape the parts that it tries to evaluate?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using PowerShell V3 then use the new `--%` operator e.g.:

```
tf.exe status --% /workspace:workspacename;*
```

Everything after `--%` until the end of the line is not evaluated by PowerShell.  It behaves kind of like cmd.exe in this zone. For more info on `--%` see this [blog post](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/powershell-v3-ctp2-provides-better-argument-passing-to-exes/).

Comment: Thenks. I'll try this. Another question - how do I find the version of PowerShell that I'm running?

Comment: $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Comment: Thenks. It turns out I run 3.0.-1.-1 already. Another question - is there a echoargs program also for cmd.exe?

Comment: If you're using echoargs.exe from the PowerShell Community Extensions (http://pscx.codeplex.com), it works in cmd.exe as well.